# The execinfo.h header file does not exist

Tags: c, linux, cygwin

I'm using the latest `cygwin 1.7.34(0.285/5/3)` full version. The issue I came across is that there was no `execinfo.h`, so a compiler prints error messages about absence of the file. How can I fix that problem? Has someone already faced that issue?

Answer (score 13):

This header is Linux specific.  If the functionality is optional, you should `#ifdef __linux__` the `#include <execinfo.h>` as well as any code chunks requiring `backtrace` or `backtrace_symbols`.

Comment: This header also seems to exist and work fine on macOS. But what can we use as an alternative for Windows, Android, web, etc?